# Non-printable (0xFF) byte in C++ source file

Tags: c++, editor

This particular C++ code project has 0xFF byte markers that prefix function definitions.

What is the purpose of this? Is it to aid some simple source file parser?

Apparently the compiler ignores these markers.

[image: Strange character appearing in C source file]

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't belong there.

Comment: Maybe its using a compiler extension that allows identifiers to use more than the basic source character set?

Comment: Woops, my mistake. It is C++ code.

Comment: +1 just for the world's ugliest coding style.  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That could be [Form Feed (ASCII 12) (on ***wiki-pedia***)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break), in other words a whitespace character.

> The form feed character is sometimes used in plain text files of source code as a delimiter for a page break, or as marker for sections of code. **Some editors, in particular emacs, have built-in commands to page up/down on the form feed character**. This convention is predominantly used in Lisp code, and is also seen in Python source code.

It used to be common in sources back when source code was commonly printed on paper for review/archival.

Prints will interpret `FF` in plain text documents as a 'page break'

Semi-relevant: https://twitter.com/sehetw/status/297904888321544192

Comment: That worked well with Fortran, where a function that comprised only 30 lines of code, excluding comments, was deemed short. Maybe too short! That doesn't work so well with C++ where you have lots of very short functions.

Comment: Thanks sehe. That must be the reason!

Comment: And to be absolutely clear: form-feed is a whitespace character, as are vertical tab and the more common space, tab and newline.

Comment: The first line after the quote makes me feel ancient.

Comment: @molbdnilo I still sometimes print code for review. Although, I don't actually use FF chars anymore :) (I still remember how they would render as ♀ on MSDOS)

Comment: The question seems to be asking about 0xFF, whereas your answer is talking about the Form Feed (FF) character.

Comment: @Rufflewind Most of us had reached the conclusion that it was FF a few years ago; Indeed the screenshot has always been crystal clear on that :)

Comment: Lesson of the day: 68.4% of the time, the question is inaccurate. Because, had the question been accurate, it wouldn't have had to be asked.